# Format date from lookup table

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

My report has a data lookup table with dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` formart. When I bring it into Crystal it changes the data type to date-time instead of just date.

I tried converting to just a date within Crystal, but when I run a lookup based on  parameters (10-1-2016 - 10-31-2016) I get a running cycle of dates. As soon as it hits 10-31-2016 it starts over from 10-1-2016.

I tried setting it to not provider duplicate values to no avail. How I could be doing this better?

Comment: does your database table has different date and time values?

Comment: The running cycle of dates is curious behavior. How are your groups nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to *display* the date without the time value, you can format the field when it displays in your report as "System Default Short Format" in the Format Editor. (*Date and Time* tab)

Otherwise leave the date as-is and create a seperate Formula `Date({table.Field})` to use as "just the date". This way you keep the original datetime value as-is, but can use your new Formula when the time value needs to be removed.